# Inserting current time to Cassandra using cassandra-cli?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I'm trying to insert a time value to my `Cassandra` column family using this command.

```
set User['1234']['lastUpdated']='2013-07-18T10:10:00.000Z';
```

I've created my column family as follows:

```
create column family User
    with comparator=UTF8Type
    and default_validation_class=UTF8Type;
```

And when I execute the command, I'm getting the following

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: Unknown timeuuid
>   representation: 2013-07-18T10:10:00.000Z.

Comment: which version of cassandra??? the looks fine to me

Comment: The version is 1.2.6. It is working now. I have no idea what caused the error. Will investigate and post it as a comment if I find anything!!